# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'

Tags: python, tensorflow

python初心者なのですがエラーが解消できません。

コードは

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(3.0, tf.float32)
b = tf.constant(2.0, tf.float32)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

y = a * x + b

sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(y,{x: [0,1,2,3]}))
```

エラー内容は

```
module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'
```

macを使用しておりpythonは3.7になります。

tensorflowは2.0.0になります

Answer (score 1):

#### 可能性1: v1の文法のコードをv2をインポートして実行している。

対策方法1: v1をインポートし、v2を無効化する。

```py
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

対策方法2: v2のコードに置き換える。

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(3.0, tf.float32)
b = tf.constant(2.0, tf.float32)

def f(x):
    return a * x + b

print(f([0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

※対策方法1と対策方法2は、どちらか一方だけを適用します。

#### 可能性2: 自分で作ったファイル名に"tensorflow.py"がある。

対策方法: ファイル名を置き換える。

```
mv tensorflow.py example.py
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37383812/tensorflow-module-object-has-no-attribute-placeholder