# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'について

Tags: python, python3, tensorflow

以下のコードを実行すると

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'

と表示されます。どうしてでしょうか？

```
import tensorflow as tf　　
sess = tf.Session()
hello  = tf.constant('Hello')
print(sess.run(hello))
```

Comment: 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session' でググると、Versionの問題でエラーになる事例がヒットしてます。ご自身の環境と照らし合わせてググってみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 英語版記事でTF2.0にSession()は無くなったとか。[Tensorflow 2.0 - AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55142951/9014308) 関連してそうなIssueはこれ。[tensorflow/tensorflow#26816](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26816) 日本で最近の類似問題だとこれとか。[module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/59745/26370)

Answer (score 1):

tensorflow 2.0では、tf.Sessionやtf.placeholderは使いません。
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate

> Every `v1.Session.run` call should be replaced by a **Python function**.
>   - The `feed_dict` and `v1.placeholder`s become **function arguments**.
>   - The fetches become the **function's return value**.
>   - During conversion eager execution allows easy debugging with standard Python tools like pdb.
>   After that add a `tf.function` decorator to make it run efficiently in graph.

Sessionの代わりに、pythonの普通の関数として実行します。

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.backend import eval

def example(x, c):
    return c

hello  = tf.constant('Hello')
f = tf.function(example)
print(eval(f([], hello)))
```

v1でfeed_dictで渡していたものは、関数の引数(この場合はx)に渡すように変更されたようです。ただし、通常は引数として渡されたxの値(v1におけるplaceholder)は他の定数(tf.constant)等と演算するなど、なんらかの処理をして返り値を出力するように関数を作ります。v2での変更点としては、placeholderが関数の引数に変わったということです。

定数等のテンソルの内容をどうしても見たい場合はkerasバックエンドのevalを使えば見れます。なので、定数の値をただ評価する場合は、関数を作らずにkerasバックエンドの`eval(hello)`などとすれば実行できます。